# call php function every 10mins for 1hour

Tags: php

got this code that should check if url is available and also give me ping:

```
<?php
function test ($url){
$starttime = microtime(true);
$valid = @fsockopen($url, 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
$stoptime = microtime(true);
echo (round(($stoptime-$starttime)*1000)).' ms.';

if (!$valid) {
   echo "Status - Failure";
} else {
   echo "Status - Success";
}
}

test('google.com');
?>
```

How do i make it so this function would be called every lets say 10minues for 1hour (6times in total) ?

Comment: Are you running it from the command line or a web server? Web servers have a time limit to run a script so it wouldn't work there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to make use of [cron jobs](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron_%28Unix%29) if you are using a Unix server or Windows Task Scheduler in the case of windows.

Like this you will be able to use programmed tasks.

In the case of using `cron` you could do it easily like this:

```
*/10 * * * *  php -f your_relative_or_full_path_URL/params > /dev/null
```

Answer (score 1):

depends: do you want to do that just once?

Then you can call the function inside a loop and use `sleep()` after each execution of the loop.

Do you want to do it everyday? or one specific day each week/month? use a cron.

Answer (score 1):

Use a simple for-loop and the [sleep](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php) command:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++) { // Run the code 6 times
    test($url);
    sleep(10 * 60); // Sleep 10 Minutes
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Send Email every day in a Month. I used it in daily backup mail..**

```
<?php 
  ignore_user_abort(true); //if page is closed its make it live
  for($i=0;$i<=30;$i++)
  {
     $to = "someone@exmple.com";
     $subject = "Test mail $i";
     $message = "Hello! This is a simple email message.";
     $from = "from@example.com";
     $headers = "From:" . $from;
     mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
     sleep(24*60);//send mail in every 24 hour. 
}

?>
```